# Creating Xamarin forms project problems(over 1600 errors)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, project

First time I installed Xamarin pack, I had windows 7, VS IDE Community 2015.
I've update the OS to windows 10, updated VS (encountered problems with both online install and iso). Same problems.

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you - you'll need to provide more info about errors.

Some starter questions:

1. Are those Xamarin.Android errors dealing with Resources. Then increase your target framework and check if Android SDK is properly installed (API levels needed)
2. If errors are Xamarin.iOS related - check your connection to Mac Build Host.